# Using a sass variable in nth child class

Tags: css, sass

How can i get the number from the sass variable and inject it into my nth child selector?

```
    @each $num in $number {
      &:nth-child($num) {
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find an example in the docs, https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/control/for

Basically you escape the value using `#{}`, so in your case:

```scss
@each $num in $number {
  &:nth-child(#{$num}) {
  }
}
```